# Error: [ng:areq]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting error ng:areq with the following code.please help me to figure out where it is causing.Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>``
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>This is example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldMessage">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function HelloWorldMessage($scope){
$scope.helloMessage="Hello World";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what version of angular is this? Anonymous controllers and blank `ng-app` are not allowed in current versions of angular.

Comment: angular.min.js-1.4.3

Comment: here is an article on the breaking change to angular which is impacting your code: http://wildermuth.com/2014/11/11/Angular_1_3_and_Breaking_Change_for_Controllers

Answer (score 0):

notice that your controller is not defined you just defined a function ,, you need to create a module first

```
angular.module("app",[]);
```

and then add you controller to this module using this line

```
angular.module("app").controller("HelloWorldMessage", HelloWorldMessage);
```

this way your code will work properly

Comment: var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);      myApp.controller("HelloWorldMessage",
function HelloWorldMessage($scope)
{
 $scope.helloMessage="Hello AngularJs";
}
); still it's not working.getting same error.

Comment: sorry.i placed angular.min.js in head section.it works fine.Thanks!